# Read a session variable and delete it after reading the value

Tags: c#

I need to read a value from a session variable.

If the session variable exists I want to delete it after reading the value.

To read the session variable I tried the following options:

```
String session1 = context.Session["test"] as String;

var session2 = context.Session["test"];
```

The first one gives me null and the second one the value I expected.

Why?

How should I read a session variable, check if exists and if it does read the value and delete the session variable?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: The first one is giving you null because whatever is in Session["test"] is NOT a string and so that "as" is returning to you a null.

Comment: What is the data type of the actuyal session variable?  Is it a string?  if not, that might be your problem.  See the [documentation](http://scspfprd01/IT/APPDEV/DN/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/):  "The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception. "

Comment: This may help.  http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/06/when-not-to-use-c-keyword.html

Comment: You are right ... I the value was an integer and not a string ... That is why I got the difference between the two code lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the session value exists, read the value and then remove it, like this:

```
if(context.Session["test"] != null)
{
    // Read value
    string sessionValue = context.Session["test"].ToString();

    // Delete value from session
    context.Session.Remove("test");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `??` for avoiding null value

```
   String session1 = context.Session["test"] as String ?? String.Empty;
```

Comment: But if I want to remove it after don't I need to check if it does exist?

Comment: butt this is not removing the session variable

Comment: if you want to remove it after...just do it          context.Session.Remove("test");